# What is the best practice when polling for sensor values?

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors

I'm working on an application where I periodically need to get a sensor value. For this I'm using AlarmManager and a Receiver at set intervals. Android's sensor implementation seems to be focused around continuous reading of data, and it does not seem possible to poll for the a single current reading.

My question is what the best practice is for "simulating" a poll mechanism? Are there any examples out there that I haven't come across? One approach is to just call registerListener(), get the current reading, and then call stopListener(). But, this does not seem to work as the reading is not available instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same approach I used [in this project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll) for polling locations. Use a `WakeLock` to keep the device awake, and have the service register the sensor listener in `onStartCommand()`. When the sensor event arrives, release the `WakeLock` and call `stopSelf()` to shut down the service.

Comment: I feel that the Github example is a little overkill for this task. I think I just need to know how to monitor when the event arrives.

By the way: It is a widget which needs these periodic updates, and I'm trying to read the pressure/barometer value from the device using SensorEventListener, which is quite different from LocationManager.

Comment: Also, it only needs to work in Honeycomb. Could BroadcastReceiver.PendingResult be used?

Comment: @hpe: "I feel that the Github example is a little overkill for this task." -- you are welcome to your opinion. "Could BroadcastReceiver.PendingResult be used?" -- not reliably, as you may not get a sensor event fast enough. Please read the docs for `goAsync()`: http://goo.gl/rLxj4

Comment: Nothing personal :) But, I gave it a try, and now it works! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Can your Github example be adapted to use with accelerometer sensor? Or, would AlarmManager be useful in this case seeing that the accelerometer sensor constantly run and output results. I don't want `onSensorChanged` to always run, but instead, run on a timer basis which I think AlarmManager may help - but not sure. Sorry, I did not mean to hijack hanspeide's post, but my requirement is similar to his regarding polling of sensors.

Comment: @ChuongPham: "Can your Github example be adapted to use with accelerometer sensor?" -- sorta, I suppose. Sensors are unreliable in the background, as some device manufacturers shut them down to save battery, particularly on older devices. Another significant difference is that you'll want to collect a set of readings so you can do data smoothing, as the accelerometer is rather twitchy.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks, Mark. Yeah, I guess when it comes to accelerometer, there's no one strategy that will suffice. I'll try a few things and see how I go. By the way, your Github space contains quite a few good examples, Wakelock being one...